# assign approval group form customization

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have to add a display field in assign approval group form when the user choose a value in the position, will display the employee name of that position in the display item field. I've tried to added the select into statement in the key-listval of that item but it won't work, I want to know which trigger and where to put my select into statement ?

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear, but it sounds like you might want the `when-validate-item` trigger.

Comment: Hello, I've tried when-validate-item trigger, but it is still not showing the value .